# Migrating a library

Tags: library, document-migration

I have a library containing 60gb of documents on Farm A that I need to move to a new library in Farm B.

What is the best method for this?

Export-SPWeb is probably the preferred solution but the problem is it needs to write 60gb of temp files to the C:\Users*\AppData\Local\Temp\ folder and our C drive does not have that much space.

I'm currently investigating Copy-Item and XCOPY but I would be interested to hear any other approaches/solutions.

Comment: Can you open both libraries in file explorer and just copy-paste all the contents? 60GB is not that much.

Comment: @GintasK Yeah that's what i'm resorting to but the problem is that both farms geo-location means the job takes nearly 24 hours meaning that the copy job will stall when there's an error. Currently investigating Copy-Item and XCOPY...

Answer (score 0):

Install ShareGate as a Trial, if you like, buy it :)
Otherwise Powershell commands could work using export-spweb !

Comment: Thanks. It looks as though Import-SPWeb is out of the question because my new library is on a Site Collection. I guess I will investigate 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Sharegate or Metalogix both have great migration tools. I suggest going with a 3rd party app over writing your own as these tools already consider: folders, files, document sets, other custom content types, permissions, version settings, metadata, etc.